# How do I make my return statement not return with parenthesis and commas?

Tags: python, list, return

So right now I'm trying to return a statement and print it but it returns with parenthesis:

```
def greeting(x):
    sp=x.split()
    return "Hello! I am ",sp[0],"and I am ",sp[1],". My favorite hobby is", sp[1]


x=input("What is your name,age, and hobby(spaced, no commas) \n")
print(greeting(x))
```

And it runs:

```
What is your name,age, and hobby(spaced, no commas) 
Jed 25 swimming

('Hello! I am ', 'Jed', 'and I am ', '25', '. My favorite hobby is', '25')
```

How do print it without the parenthesis and commas?

Comment: F-strings: `return f"Hello! I am {sp[0]} and I am {sp[1]}. My favorite hobby is {sp[2]}"`

Comment: `print(''.join(greeting(x)))`

Comment: Did you mean: `print(*greeting(x))`?

Comment: `print(*greeting(x), sep="")`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's not clear what you actually want the code to do, probably because of a lack of understanding of the problem. There are two completely different things you could have in mind: do you want the function to *create the actual string* for printing? Or do you want *the printing process* to take the resulting tuple and format it? Either way, it's not clear that you actually understand *what happens* when you call the function. Just to make sure - do you understand what a *tuple* is?

Comment: Maybe print(' '.join(greeting(x)))? And at the end of the return statement it should be sp[2].

Answer (score 2):

```
return "Hello! I am ",sp[0],"and I am ",sp[1],". My favorite hobby is", sp[1]
```

The value is returned with commas because *that's what you told it to do*.  (You can join values with commas inside a `print()` call and the result will be a single string message, but that's a special case.)

If you want to return a single string, then use `+` instead of `,`:

```
return "Hello! I am " + sp[0] + "and I am " + sp[1] + ". My favorite hobby is" + sp[1]
```

Or use f-string as Johnny Mopp suggested.

Answer (score 0):

From my end, I can suggest one of two ways to do this.

First is using f strings as [Johnny Mopp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669576/johnny-mopp) has mentioned:

```py
return f"Hello! I am {sp[0]} and I am {sp[1]}. My favorite hobby is {sp[2]}"
```

Second, I can't remember what these are called exaclty(if you do, please let me know), but this is a pretty cool and simple way to concatenate in python:

```py
return "Hello!, I am {}, and I am {}. My favorite hobby is {}".format(sp[0], sp[1], sp[2])
```

In the second method, you basically put a `{}` everywhere you need a variable to be and after the string, you add `.format()` at the end and inside the parameters you specify each of the variables in the order that you had the `{}`'s in the string and voila, you have your string there.